# Scipiy.optimize.minimaze unconstrained error

Tags: python, scipy

I want to perform constrained least square methon for polynom. Before that, i decided to try unconstrined optimalization. Here is the problem:

My polynom looks like

$f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$

So I want to find best coefficients a, b, c, d and e. Function that I want to minimize thus looks like

```
def lsq(args, x, y):
    return sum([(y[i] - (args[0]*x[i]**4 + args[1]*x[i]**3 + args[2]*x**2 + args[3]*x + args[4]))**2
                for i in np.arange(len(x))])
```

Where `x` and `y` are lists of coordinates of my points. Thus, my code may look like:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
pH = np.array([8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,3,2,2,2,1])
def rank2(y):
    return np.array([(i+1)/len(y) for i in range(len(y))])
x = rank2(pH)
y = pH
def lsq(args, x, y):
    return sum([(y[i] - (args[0]*x[i]**4 + args[1]*x[i]**3 + args[2]*x**2 + args[3]*x + args[4]))**2
                for i in np.arange(len(x))])


params = scipy.optimize.minimize(nejmensi_ctverce, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], args = (x, y))
```

But here I got a error:

```
File "C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-3.6.1.0Qt5\python-
3.6.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 628, in _approx_fprime_helper
grad[k] = (f(*((xk + d,) + args)) - f0) / d[k]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Can you help me? I guess I do not cempletely understand how to parse arguments for `minimize` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `x`s in `lsq` were not indexed by `i`:

```
args[0]*x[i]**4 + args[1]*x[i]**3 + args[2]*x**2 + args[3]*x + args[4]
                                         ---^           ---^
```

This led `lsq` to returning an array of values instead of a scalar:

```
In [9]: lsq([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], x, y)
Out[9]: 
array([ 468.00714962,  458.38490951,  448.01979096,  436.95911906,
        425.25433416,  412.9609918 ,  400.13876277,  386.85143307,
        373.16690395,  359.15719185,  344.89842847,  330.47086072,
        315.95885075,  301.45087591,  287.0395288 ,  272.82151724,
        258.89766428,  245.37290818])
```

This leads to a `ValueError` since `scipy.optimize.minimze` expects `lsq` to return scalar values to be minimized.
So one way to fix the problem is to replace the bare `x`s with `x[i]`s.

A better way to solve the problem is to replace all the `x[i]`s with `x`s, remove the `for i in np.arange(len(x))` and use [NumPy array-based arithmetic](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations):

```
def lsq(args, x, y):
    return ((y - (args[0]*x**4 + args[1]*x**3 + args[2]*x**2 
                  + args[3]*x + args[4]))**2).sum()
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

pH = np.array([8,8,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,3,2,2,2,1])
def rank2(y):
    return np.array([(i+1)/len(y) for i in range(len(y))])
x = rank2(pH)
y = pH

def lsq(args, x, y):
    a, b, c, d, e = args
    return ((y - (a*x**4 + b*x**3 + c*x**2 + d*x + e))**2).sum()

params = optimize.minimize(lsq, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], args = (x, y))
print(params.x)
```

yields

```
[  94.48618936 -211.42358992  144.93063545  -37.24078798   10.23934514]
```

with a minimum `lsq` value of:

```
print(lsq(params.x, x, y))
# 6.91284752049
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params = scipy.optimize.minimize(nejmensi_ctverce, np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]), args = (x, y))
```